# Problem setting the best move in the Negamax algorithm

Tags: python, chess, alpha-beta-pruning, negamax

Hey i am tring to make a chess engine but when i run the code it plays fine, the problem is sometimes it does not set the best move and it shows an error becuase the search did not return a move to play. My negamax includes AB pruning, MD Pruning, QSearch, ID, and TT Tables. Here is my implementation.

```py
    Entry=namedtuple('Entry', 'score depth flag')
    
    class Search():
        def __init__(self):
            self.nodes=0
            self.tt_score={}
    
        def search(self,position,api):
            self.nodes=0
            for depth in range(1,1000):
                ret=self.negamax(position,api,-INFINITY,INFINITY,depth,ply=1)
                yield ret
    
        def negamax(self,position,api,alpha,beta,depth=3,ply=1):
            best,bmove=-INFINITY,()
            for move in position.moves():
                score=self.negasearch(position.move(move),-beta,-alpha,depth-1,ply+1)
                if score>=beta: return [move,score,self.nodes]
                if score>best:
                    best,bmove=score,move
                    #api.arrow("clear")
                    #api.arrow(coordinates[move[0]]+coordinates[move[1]])
                    if score>alpha: alpha=score
            return [bmove,best,self.nodes]
    
        def negasearch(self,position,alpha,beta,depth,ply):
            best,aorig=-INFINITY,alpha
            self.nodes+=1
            if MATE-ply<beta:
                beta=MATE-ply
                if alpha>=MATE-ply: return MATE-ply
            if -MATE+ply>alpha:
                alpha=-MATE+ply
                if beta<=-MATE+ply: return -MATE+ply
            entry=self.tt_score.get(position.hash(),Entry(0,-1,'exact'))
            if entry.depth>=depth:
                if entry.flag=='exact': return entry.score
                elif entry.flag=='lower': alpha=max(alpha,entry.score)
                elif entry.flag=='upper': beta=min(beta,entry.score)
                if alpha>=beta: return entry.score
            if depth<=0: return self.qsearch(position,alpha,beta,ply+1)
            for move in position.moves():
                score=self.negasearch(position.move(move),-beta,-alpha,depth-1,ply+1)
                if score>=beta:
                    best=score
                    break
                if score>best:
                    best=score
                    if score>alpha: alpha=score
            if best<=aorig: self.tt_score[position.hash()]=Entry(best,depth,'upper')
            elif best>=beta: self.tt_score[position.hash()]=Entry(best,depth,'lower')
            else: self.tt_score[position.hash()]=Entry(best,depth,'exact')
            return best
    
        def qsearch(self,position,alpha,beta,ply):
            stand_pat=position.score
            if stand_pat>=beta: return beta
            if alpha<stand_pat: alpha=stand_pat
            self.nodes+=1
            for move in position.moves():
                if move[2]==0: continue
                score=self.qsearch(position.move(move),-beta,-alpha,ply+1)
                if score>=beta: return beta
                if score>alpha: alpha=score
            return alpha
```

You probably have already noticed i did not negate the score each turn as it should be. Reason why is because when you call the move function it return the position with the score already negated. For example,

```py
    def move(self,move):
        # copy the current position board, turn, and score
        # if move is a capture then preform:
        #     score+=pvs[pieceBeingCaptured]
        # preform move
        # if the next player is mated after this move then set score to MATE
        return Position(board,-score,self.turn*-1)
```

It is not the move generation because it returns the correct moves each position state. With the best value being -INFINITY and negamax it should always set the best move. Any help would be helpful.

Comment: I would look into obtaining the best move from the principal variation line instead. You can obtain it e.g. like this: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Triangular_PV-Table